# Ошибка в Internet Explorer 8 при обработке объявления xmlns:xml

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

В проекте используются xslt преобразования на стороне клиента. Internet Explorer 8 выдает ошибку при обработке
**<env:Fault xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">**
Текст ошибки:

> Не допускается, чтобы префикс пространства имен начинался с зарезервированной строки "xml". Ошибка при обработке ресурса ''...
> **</wsse:BinarySecurityToken></wsse:Security><smev:Header wsu:Id="ID-0cf2766d-7273-4aa5-abed-5ce834d99e35" xmln...**

После тестов было выяснено что ругается именно на объявление "xmlns:xml".
Internet Explorer 9, Firefox, Opera, Chrome ошибок не выдают.
Сам файл XML приходит при электронном документообороте (SOAP). Нет возможности изменить файл с данными.
Кто нибудь встречался с приведенной ошибкой? Как разрешить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

[@irockez](/users/8387/irockez), Ммм... Смэв...

> "The namespace whose name is
> http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace is bound by definition to
> the prefix xml: according to  Namespaces in XML (and by Namespaces in XML 1.1).
> Note that unlike all other XML namespaces, both the name and
> the prefix are specified; 
> i.e., if you want XML 1.0 processors to recognize this namespace, you must use
> the reserved prefix xml:.
> "

Вообще, если нет возможности изменить исходный файл, и всё происходит на стороне клиента - УВЫ помочь ничем не можем. Чисто физически. Это ошибка генератора сервиса. Вы или принимаете эту пургу себе, обрабатываете, сериализуете, чистите, возвращаете, или ничего не делаете:) Чисто для интереса, какой SID этого сервиса? Глянул бы на днях, для себя. Тоже Мэв'ом занимаюсь

Comment: SID0003525
ФНС Выписка из ЕГРИП/ЕГРЮЛ
Тогда только один допустимый выход: преобразования на стороне сервера.

Comment: @irockez, печально, но `Сервис стал доступен 25.10.2012 01:18:25`. Есть линковка на тестовую WSDL?

Comment: С Федеральным сервисом работаем уже месяца 2. Он публичный, почти всегда отвечает.